# repeat javascript calculation and display to table

Tags: javascript

I have some working JavaScript. I am wanting the script to forecast over 12 months and display the results in a table (month for month).

Of the 12 month table - Row 1 will be the code as below.

Row 2 will be the end balance ("amount" variable) of month 1.... and the script repeats calculating the interest, fee, vat then endbalance etc... so month 2 end balance will be also month 3 start balance....

Really appreciate if anyone can help me get this completed. - I do not know much Javascript - I have ahcieved this so far based on baisc knowledge and past help from answers.

https://codepen.io/george-richardson/pen/VRGPdV

**Current Calculation & Display Result - JS**

```
function myfunction() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var startBalance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("startBalance").value);
  var interestRate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("interestRate").value);
  var fee = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fee").value);
  parseFloat(document.getElementById("interestRate").value);
  var vat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("vat").value);



  interestRate = interestRate / 100;
  fee = fee / 100;
  vat = vat / 100;

  var simpleInt = startBalance * interestRate;
  var profitfee = simpleInt * fee;
  var afterVAT = profitfee * vat;
  var amount = (startBalance + simpleInt - profitfee - afterVAT).toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById("siOutput-00").innerHTML = "Investment: £" + startBalance.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("siOutput-01").innerHTML = "Return: £" + simpleInt.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("siOutput-02").innerHTML = "Fee: £" + profitfee.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("siOutput-002").innerHTML = "VAT: £" + afterVAT.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("siOutput-03").innerHTML = "End Balance: £" + amount;
}
```

**Current HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="test">
<form id="siForm onkeyup="myfunction()"">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="startBalance">Start Balance</label>
        <input type="text" onkeyup="myfunction()" class="form-control" id="startBalance" placeholder="Enter amount without dollar sign">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="interestRate">Interest Rate</label>
        <input type="text" onkeyup="myfunction()" class="form-control" id="interestRate" placeholder="Example: 12%">
      </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fee">Fee</label>
        <input type="text" onkeyup="myfunction()" class="form-control" id="fee" placeholder="Example: 12%">
      </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="vat">VAT</label>
        <input type="text" onkeyup="myfunction()" class="form-control" id="vat" placeholder="Example: 12%">
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p class="lead mt-3" id="siOutput-00"></p>
      <p class="lead mt-3" id="siOutput-01"></p>
      <p class="lead mb-3" id="siOutput-02"></p>
      <p class="lead mb-3" id="siOutput-002"></p>
       <p class="lead mb-3" id="siOutput-03"></p>
    </div>
```

**12 Month Table For JS Output**

```
<style>
                                                .forecast table,
                    .forecast tr,
                    .forecast td,
                    .forecast th {
                      border: 1px solid;
                      border-collapse: collapse;
                    }
                            </style>

<table class="forecast table table-striped" id="forecast">
<tr><th scope="col">Month</th><th scope="col">Start</th>
<th scope="col">Return</th><th scope="col">Fee</th><th scope="col">VAT</th><th scope="col">End</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td class="test"></td><td class="test><td class="test></td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"><td class="test></td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"></td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"><td class="test></td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"></td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"><td class="test></td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"></td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"><td class="test></td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"></td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"><td class="test></td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"></td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"><td class="test></td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"></td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"><td class="test></td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"></td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"><td class="test></td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"></td></tr>
<tr><td>10</td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"><td class="test></td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"></td></tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"><td class="test></td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"></td></tr>
<tr><td>12</td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"><td class="test></td><td class="test"></td><td class="test"></td></tr>
```

**Research - starting point of 12 month table output**

```
const td = document.querySelectorAll("#forecast td.test");
 for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
 td[i*2].textContent = 
 td[i*2+1].textContent =
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet ? Because in this state it is difficult to understand

Comment: https://codepen.io/george-richardson/pen/VRGPdV for the current working JS , You can copy and paste the forecast table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it this way :

```js
function myfunction() {
  event.preventDefault();
  doForecast(0);
}

function doForecast(index){
  var nextIndex = index+1;
  var startBalance = null;
  if(index == 0){
    startBalance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("startBalance"+index).value);
  } else {
    startBalance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount"+index).innerHTML);
  }
  
  var interestRate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("interestRate").value);
  var fee = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fee").value);
  parseFloat(document.getElementById("interestRate").value);
  var vat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("vat").value);
  
  interestRate = interestRate / 100;
  fee = fee / 100;
  vat = vat / 100;
  
  var simpleInt = startBalance * interestRate;
  var profitfee = simpleInt * fee;
  var amendedBalance = simpleInt - profitfee;
  var afterVAT = amendedBalance * vat;
  var amount = (startBalance + simpleInt - profitfee - afterVAT).toFixed(2);
  
  var stringIndex = ""+(nextIndex);
  document.getElementById("startBalance"+stringIndex).innerHTML = startBalance.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("simpleInt"+stringIndex).innerHTML = simpleInt.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("profitfee"+stringIndex).innerHTML = profitfee.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("afterVAT"+stringIndex).innerHTML = afterVAT.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("amount"+stringIndex).innerHTML = amount;
  if( nextIndex < 12){
    doForecast(nextIndex);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="test">
  <form id="siForm" onkeyup="myfunction()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="startBalance">Start Balance</label>
      <input type="text" onkeyup="myfunction()" class="form-control" id="startBalance0" placeholder="Enter amount without dollar sign">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="interestRate">Interest Rate</label>
      <input type="text" onkeyup="myfunction()" class="form-control" id="interestRate" placeholder="Example: 12%">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fee">Fee</label>
      <input type="text" onkeyup="myfunction()" class="form-control" id="fee" placeholder="Example: 12%">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="vat">VAT</label>
      <input type="text" onkeyup="myfunction()" class="form-control" id="vat" placeholder="Example: 12%">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSimple">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<style>
  .forecast table,
  .forecast tr,
  .forecast td,
  .forecast th {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
</style>

<table class="forecast table table-striped" id="forecast">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Month</th>
    <th scope="col">Start</th>
    <th scope="col">Return</th>
    <th scope="col">Fee</th>
    <th scope="col">VAT</th>
    <th scope="col">End</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td >
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="startBalance1"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="simpleInt1"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="profitfee1"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="afterVAT1"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="amount1"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td >
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="startBalance2"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="simpleInt2"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="profitfee2"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="afterVAT2"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="amount2"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td >
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="startBalance3"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="simpleInt3"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="profitfee3"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="afterVAT3"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="amount3"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td >
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="startBalance4"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="simpleInt4"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="profitfee4"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="afterVAT4"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="amount4"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td >
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="startBalance5"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="simpleInt5"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="profitfee5"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="afterVAT5"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="amount5"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td >
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="startBalance6"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="simpleInt6"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="profitfee6"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="afterVAT6"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="amount6"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td >
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="startBalance7"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="simpleInt7"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="profitfee7"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="afterVAT7"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="amount7"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td >
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="startBalance8"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="simpleInt8"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="profitfee8"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="afterVAT8"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="amount8"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td >
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="startBalance9"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="simpleInt9"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="profitfee9"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="afterVAT9"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="amount9"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td >
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="startBalance10"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="simpleInt10"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="profitfee10"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="afterVAT10"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="amount10"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td >
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="startBalance11"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="simpleInt11"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="profitfee11"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="afterVAT11"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="amount11"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td >
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="startBalance12"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="simpleInt12"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="profitfee12"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="afterVAT12"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>£</span>
      <span id="amount12"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The table is fully populate when you have choose all parameters.

Code also available here : https://codepen.io/sebbousquet/pen/oVPwxE

**EDIT** : Add GBP symbol in each cell (codepen also updated)

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much Sir.

Comment: Sorry, please can you add GBP sign to each colum? I tired but get NAN error even when trying "£" + .... it picks up the currency sign to do month 2 and fails

Comment: Ok, I look for a solution but it's not enough to add it to the column title ?

Comment: @GeorgeRichardson I found a solution, I'm updating the code and I let you know when it's done

Comment: @GeorgeRichardson Done ;)

Comment: wonder if you could help me if you don't mind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264275/how-to-add-to-a-javascript-calculation-at-specific-index