# How to add to a JavaScript calculation at specific Index

Tags: javascript

I have some fully working Javascript that is doing some calculations and displaying them into a table - its a 12 row table that represents a 12 month Forecast

I added the  fields - **(additionalInvestment)** and **(month)** -- I want it so say in any of the input fields I put  e.g. :

1000 (additionalAmount) 2 (month) - the javascript will add the value 1000 to the start balance of month 2.... (equivalent to Index2) in the script... so say the month 1 end balance is 1000 - the script makes month 2 start balance what month 1 end balance is etc etc - but if one set of the input fields are 1000 (additionalAmount) and (month) 2 it will add 1000 to the start balance of month 2.... If i put month 3 in the second set of input fields it would add X value to month 3 start balance...

https://codepen.io/george-richardson/pen/RdYjPJ

Ignore the script for forecastClient (dates)

```js
function forecastClient() {

    const bankHolidays = new Set([
        Date.parse("April, 19 2019"),
        Date.parse("April, 22 2019"),
        Date.parse("May, 6 2019"),
        Date.parse("May, 27 2019"),
        Date.parse("August, 26 2019"),
        Date.parse("December, 25 2019"),
        Date.parse("December, 26 2019"),
        Date.parse("January, 1 2020"),
    ]);

    function addWorkingDays(date, days) {
        function workingDay(date) {
            while (true) {
                let day = (date.getDay() + 1) % 7;
                if (day < 2)
                    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2 - day);
                if (!bankHolidays.has(date.getTime())) break;
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            }
        }
        workingDay(date);
        while (days--) {
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            workingDay(date);
        }
        return date;
    }

    const dateStr = document.querySelector("#startdate").value.replace(/-/g, "/");
    const date = new Date(dateStr);
    addWorkingDays(date, 0); // Make sure it is a working day
    const td = document.querySelectorAll("#forecast td.date-forecast");
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        td[i * 2].textContent = date.toDateString();
        td[i * 2 + 1].textContent = addWorkingDays(date, 27).toDateString();
        addWorkingDays(date, 1);
    }
};

function myfunction() {
    event.preventDefault();
    doForecast(0);
}

function doForecast(index) {
    var nextIndex = index + 1;
    var startBalance = null;
    if (index == 0) {
        startBalance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("startBalance" + index).value);
    } else {
        startBalance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount" + index).innerHTML);
    }

    var interestRate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("interestRate").value);
    var fee = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fee").value);
    parseFloat(document.getElementById("interestRate").value);
    var vat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("vat").value);

    interestRate = interestRate / 100;
    fee = fee / 100;
    vat = vat / 100;

    var simpleInt = startBalance * interestRate;
    var profitfee = simpleInt * fee;
    var afterVAT = profitfee * vat;
    var amount = (startBalance + simpleInt - profitfee - afterVAT).toFixed(2)

    var stringIndex = "" + (nextIndex);

    document.getElementById("startBalance" + stringIndex).innerHTML = startBalance.toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById("simpleInt" + stringIndex).innerHTML = simpleInt.toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById("profitfee" + stringIndex).innerHTML = profitfee.toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById("afterVAT" + stringIndex).innerHTML = afterVAT.toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById("amount" + stringIndex).innerHTML = amount;
    if (nextIndex < 12) {
        doForecast(nextIndex);
    }
}

function start() {
    forecastClient();
    myfunction();
}
```

```html
<body onload="start();">

    <div class="form-group col-mb-3">
        <label onkeyup="" for="forecastLive">Live Date: <input value="03/27/2019" id="startdate"></label>

        <label for="startBalance">Start Balance
            <input onkeyup="myfunction()" id="startBalance0" value="1000">
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" onkeyup="myfunction()" id="interestRate" value="20">

        <input type="hidden" onkeyup="myfunction()" id="fee" value="30">

        <input type="hidden" onkeyup="myfunction()" id="vat" value="20">
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="form-group col-mb-3">
        <label for="additionalAmount">Aditional Amount
            <input onkeyup="myfunction()" id="additionalAmount1" value=""></label>
        <label for="Month">Month
            <input onkeyup="myfunction()" id="additionalMonth" value="">
        </label>
        <label for="additionalAmount">Aditional Amount
            <input onkeyup="myfunction()" id="additionalAmount2" value=""></label>
        <label for="Month">Month
            <input onkeyup="myfunction()" id="additionalMonth" value="">
        </label>

        <br>
        <br>

        <style>
            .forecast table,
            .forecast tr,
            .forecast td,
            .forecast th {
                border: 1px solid;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
        </style>

        <table class="forecast table table-striped" id="forecast" onload="myfunction()">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Month</th>
                <th scope="col">Month Start</th>
                <th scope="col">Investment</th>
                <th scope="col">Return</th>
                <th scope="col">Fee</th>
                <th scope="col">Vat</th>
                <th scope="col">Closing Balance</th>
                <th scope="col">Month End</th>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>

                <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance1"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt1"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee1"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT1"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="amount1"></span></td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance2"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt2"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee2"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT2"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="amount2"></span></td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance3"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt3"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee3"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT3"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="amount3"></span></td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance4"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt4"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee4"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT4"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="amount4"></span></td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance5"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt5"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee5"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT5"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="amount5"></span></td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance6"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt6"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee6"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT6"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="amount6"></span></td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance7"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt7"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee7"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT7"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="amount7"></span></td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance8"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt8"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee8"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT8"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="amount8"></span></td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance9"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt9"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee9"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT9"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="amount9"></span></td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance10"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt10"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee10"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT10"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="amount10"></span></td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance11"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt11"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee11"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT11"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="amount11"></span></td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>12</td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance12"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt12"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee12"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT12"></span></td>
                <td><span>£</span><span id="amount12"></span></td>
                <td class="date-forecast"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Ok, that's what you want.  Now what have you tried?

Comment: I tried giving input ID's and then in JS checking the ID's but giving them ID's , I couldn't get it to work ... and increase to the specific Month start balance , as any month can have additional amount added, it just needs adding to the correct one as indicated in the Month field, but we need multiple additionalInvestment and Month fields - I also added codenPen link to make life easier @ScottSauyet

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For instance, does the problem you're having require you to do all the column calculations, or would two or three suffice?  And rows: do we need all 12 months to understand the problem?  And are bank holidays intrinsic to what your asking?  Simplify, simplify, simplify!

Comment: Please ignore the date script that is separate but displays in each row. The script is working if you look at codePen...i Just need the script to check if any fields have additionalAmount and Month values, if so, it will add the Amount to the specified Month start balance... so if it additional amount is 1000 it will add 1000 to the current start balance of month 2...if month 2 is the month declared , 

if other input fields have additional amount 4000 and month 6 it will add that to month 6    @ScottSauyet

Comment: You miss my point.  Creating a MCVE not only makes it easier tor those trying to answer, it's also a useful technique for finding the issue yourself first.  Tracing through a wall of code, most of which is meaningless to the underlying question, is no one's idea of fun.

Comment: I see that you're new.  That's why I'm being patient.  This is definitely an improvement.  This would be improved if you could [Make a Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753) so that it can be tested inline.

Comment: I thought I saw that temporarily.  The point, though, is that it takes work to ask a good question.  It's the work that you put into it that might make it interesting for someone else to answer.  Especially important is making an example that either runs or that breaks down exactly at the point you're asking about.  Since you're asking to add a feature to working code, you should be able to demonstrate a simplified version of that working code.

Comment: Also... formatting!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it this way :

```js
function forecastClient() {

    const bankHolidays = new Set([
        Date.parse("April, 19 2019"),
        Date.parse("April, 22 2019"),
        Date.parse("May, 6 2019"),
        Date.parse("May, 27 2019"),
        Date.parse("August, 26 2019"),
        Date.parse("December, 25 2019"),
        Date.parse("December, 26 2019"),
        Date.parse("January, 1 2020"),
    ]);

    function addWorkingDays(date, days) {
        function workingDay(date) {
            while (true) {
                let day = (date.getDay() + 1) % 7;
                if (day < 2) date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2 - day);
                if (!bankHolidays.has(date.getTime())) break;
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            }
        }
        workingDay(date);
        while (days--) {
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            workingDay(date);
        }
        return date;
    }

    const dateStr = document.querySelector("#startdate").value.replace(/-/g, "/");
    const date = new Date(dateStr);
    addWorkingDays(date, 0); // Make sure it is a working day
    const td = document.querySelectorAll("#forecast td.date-forecast");
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        td[i * 2].textContent = date.toDateString();
        td[i * 2 + 1].textContent = addWorkingDays(date, 27).toDateString();
        addWorkingDays(date, 1);
    }
};

function myfunction() {
    event.preventDefault();
    doForecast(0);
}

function doForecast(index) {
    var nextIndex = index + 1;
    var startBalance = null;
    var additionalAmount = (document.getElementById("additionalAmount").value != '') ? parseFloat(document.getElementById("additionalAmount").value) : null;
    var additionalMonth = parseFloat(document.getElementById("additionalMonth").value);
  
    var additionalAmount2 = (document.getElementById("additionalAmount2").value != '') ? parseFloat(document.getElementById("additionalAmount2").value) : null;
    var additionalMonth2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("additionalMonth2").value);
  
    var additionalAmount3 = (document.getElementById("additionalAmount3").value != '') ? parseFloat(document.getElementById("additionalAmount3").value) : null;
    var additionalMonth3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("additionalMonth3").value);
  
    if (index == 0) {
        startBalance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("startBalance" + index).value);
        if( additionalMonth == 1 && additionalAmount != undefined){
          startBalance += additionalAmount;
        }
        if( additionalMonth2 == 1 && additionalAmount2 != undefined){
          startBalance += additionalAmount2;
        }
        if( additionalMonth3 == 1 && additionalAmount3 != undefined){
          startBalance += additionalAmount3;
        }
    } else {
        startBalance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount" + index).innerHTML);
        if( additionalMonth > 1 && additionalMonth == (index + 1) && additionalAmount != undefined){
          startBalance += additionalAmount;
        }
        if( additionalMonth2 > 1 && additionalMonth2 == (index + 1) && additionalAmount2 != undefined){
          startBalance += additionalAmount2;
        }
        if( additionalMonth3 > 1 && additionalMonth3 == (index + 1) && additionalAmount3 != undefined){
          startBalance += additionalAmount3;
        }
    }

    var interestRate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("interestRate").value);
    var fee = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fee").value);
    parseFloat(document.getElementById("interestRate").value);
    var vat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("vat").value);

    interestRate = interestRate / 100;
    fee = fee / 100;
    vat = vat / 100;

    var simpleInt = startBalance * interestRate;
    var profitfee = simpleInt * fee;
    var afterVAT = profitfee * vat;
    var amount = (startBalance + simpleInt - profitfee - afterVAT).toFixed(2)

    var stringIndex = "" + (nextIndex);
    document.getElementById("startBalance" + stringIndex).innerHTML = startBalance.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("simpleInt" + stringIndex).innerHTML = simpleInt.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("profitfee" + stringIndex).innerHTML = profitfee.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("afterVAT" + stringIndex).innerHTML = afterVAT.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("amount" + stringIndex).innerHTML = amount;
    if (nextIndex < 12) {
        doForecast(nextIndex);
    }
}

function start() {
    forecastClient();
    myfunction();
}
```

```html
<body onload="start();">

  <div class="form-group col-mb-3">
    <label onkeyup="" for="forecastLive">Live Date: <input value="03/27/2019" id="startdate"></label>

    <label for="startBalance">Start Balance
     <input id="startBalance0" value="1000">  
  </label>
    <input type="hidden" onkeyup="myfunction()" id="interestRate" value="20" />

    <input type="hidden" onkeyup="myfunction()" id="fee" value="30" />

    <input type="hidden" onkeyup="myfunction()" id="vat" value="20" />
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="form-group col-mb-3">
    <label for="additionalAmount">Aditional Amount
<input onkeyup="myfunction()"  id="additionalAmount" value=""></label>
    <label for="Month">Month
<input onkeyup="myfunction()"  id="additionalMonth" value="">
</label>
<br />
    <label for="additionalAmount2">Aditional Amount
<input onkeyup="myfunction()"  id="additionalAmount2" value=""></label>
    <label for="Month">Month
<input onkeyup="myfunction()"  id="additionalMonth2" value="">
</label>
<br />
    <label for="additionalAmount3">Aditional Amount
<input onkeyup="myfunction()"  id="additionalAmount3" value=""></label>
    <label for="Month">Month
<input onkeyup="myfunction()"  id="additionalMonth3" value="">
</label>

    <br>
    <br>

    <style>
      .forecast table,
      .forecast tr,
      .forecast td,
      .forecast th {
        border: 1px solid;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
    </style>

    <table class="forecast table table-striped" id="forecast" onload="myfunction()">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Month</th>
        <th scope="col">Month Start</th>
        <th scope="col">Investment</th>
        <th scope="col">Return</th>
        <th scope="col">Fee</th>
        <th scope="col">Vat</th>
        <th scope="col">Closing Balance</th>
        <th scope="col">Month End</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>

        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance1"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt1"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee1"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT1"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount1"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance2"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt2"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee2"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT2"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount2"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance3"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt3"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee3"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT3"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount3"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance4"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt4"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee4"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT4"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount4"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance5"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt5"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee5"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT5"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount5"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance6"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt6"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee6"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT6"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount6"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance7"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt7"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee7"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT7"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount7"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance8"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt8"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee8"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT8"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount8"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance9"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt9"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee9"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT9"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount9"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance10"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt10"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee10"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT10"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount10"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance11"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt11"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee11"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT11"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount11"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="startBalance12"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="simpleInt12"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="profitfee12"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="afterVAT12"></span></td>
        <td><span>£</span><span id="amount12"></span></td>
        <td class="date-forecast"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Code also available here : https://codepen.io/tmacpolo/pen/WmaRVr

**EDIT**: Update code to allow 3 amount possibilities

Comment: Your the best! Thank you very much. x

Comment: @GeorgeRichardson Codepen update with 3 Amounts possibilities